# Clipped Voronoi diagrom on a Google Map zooming incorrectly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js, voronoi

Right now I'm struggling to get this Voronoi diagram overlaid onto a Google Map correctly. I'm able to plot the centroids and lines correctly, but I am trying to clip the edges of the sections based on a given radius, one that doesn't change size based on the level of zoom (i.e. it covers the same area regardless of zoom level). The first link has the edge clipping, and the second link has the regular Voronoi working on Google Maps (with zoom), but the circles I'm using to clip the Voronoi diagram do not move correctly during the zoom.

Here's the code that I have, based on http://bl.ocks.org/njvack/1405439 and http://bl.ocks.org/shimizu/5610671:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
mapOptions);

var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
transitLayer.setMap(map);

// load the data

d3.csv("201402_station_data.csv", function(data) {

  function sanFran(d) { if (d.landmark == "San Francisco") {return d;}}
  data = data.filter(sanFran)

  var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

  overlay.onAdd = function() {

    var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
      .attr("class", "svgOverlay");
    var svg = layer.append("svg")
    var svg_overlay = svg.append("g").attr("class","voronoi")

    var paths, points, clips;
    clips = svg_overlay.append("svg:g").attr("id", "point-clips");
    points = svg_overlay.append("svg:g").attr("id", "points");
    paths = svg_overlay.append("svg:g").attr("id", "point-paths");

    overlay.draw = function() {

      var projection = this.getProjection()

      // try to get just the coordinates to use for voronoi
      var positions = []
      data.forEach(function(d) {   
        var googleCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(d.lat, d.long);
        var pixelCoordinates = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(googleCoordinates)
        positions.push([pixelCoordinates.x+4000, pixelCoordinates.y+4000])
      });

      var polygons = d3.geom.voronoi(positions)

      clips.selectAll("clipPath")
          .data(data)
          .attr('cx', function(d,i) { return positions[i][0]; })
          .attr('cy', function(d,i) { return positions[i][1]; })
          .attr('r', 30)
        .enter().append("svg:clipPath")
          .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "clip-"+i;})
        .append("svg:circle")
          .attr('cx', function(d,i) { return positions[i][0]; })
          .attr('cy', function(d,i) { return positions[i][1]; })
          .attr('r', 30);

      var pathAttr = {
        "d": function(d, i) {return "M" + polygons[i].join("L") + "Z"},
        "clip-path": function(d,i) { return "url(#clip-"+i+")"},
        "id": function(d,i) { return "path-"+i},
        fill: "red", //d3.rgb(130, 230, 230),
        'fill-opacity': 0.4,
        "stroke": d3.rgb(200,200,200)
      }

      paths.selectAll("path")
          .data(data)
          .attr(pathAttr)
        .enter().append("svg:path")
          .attr(pathAttr)

      var circleAttr = {
        "cx": function(d, i) { return positions[i][0]; },
        "cy": function(d, i) { return positions[i][1]; },
        "r": 2,
        stroke: "none"
      }

      points.selectAll("circle")
          .data(data)
          .attr(circleAttr)
        .enter().append("svg:circle")
          .attr(circleAttr)
    }
  };
  overlay.setMap(map)
});
```

Apologies if this is too close to older questions, and I appreciate any help.